# Mod_Mono, Apache, Raspberry PI

Tags: apache2, raspberry-pi3, mod-mono

I have a problem to get my asp.net site running on my Apache webserver on my Raspberry Pi. I was already looking on different online boards, but I did not find any good intstructions how to proceed.

What is already done:

- Mono Complete and Mono Develop are installed (latest version 4)
- XSP4 installed
- Apache2 installed (default website is working)
- Mod_mono (version4) installed and activated

I have generated a test website with the file "Test.aspx" and copied to the folder /var/www/Test/
Then I have created a new config-file "Test.conf" on /etc/apache2/sites-available and activated it.
The content is:

```
   DocumentRoot /var/www/Test

   <Directory /var/www/Test/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            SetHandler mono
            DirectoryIndex Test.aspx Test.html
</Directory>
```

What do I miss. I hope that someone can give me some good instructions. Thank you!

Comment: What makes you think you missed something? What happens when you make an HTTP request to the server? What does the browser show? What do the server logs show?

Comment: When I am opening the browser on localhost, it says "The requested URL /Test.aspx was not found on this server."

Comment: In the errorlogs there are two errors listed up: "No Application found for /Test.aspx" and "Host header was 'IP from RPI'"

Comment: Is there anyone, who can help me???